# Rude behavior of AlertDialog in android

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-alertdialog

Hey Guyz please help me get rid of the rude behavior of the AlertDialog.

I have a button in my fragment when clicking on it I want it to show a AlertDialog populated with the Edittext. Even I code for it.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setView(R.layout.send_message)
                    .setTitle(R.string.sendTitle + bundle.getString(USER_EXTRAS.FULLNAME_EXTRA))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.send, null)
                    .show();
```

but it prompts on 2nd line that " Call require API level 21(current min is 11) android.app.alertDialog.Builder#setView "

I want 11 as a minimum API(my recommended).

After compiling this I got the Error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.setView
```

If setView() is not supported by the API 11 which should I use instead?

Is there any alternative? and why I am getting this exception.?

Any help will be great appreciated.

Comment: `rude behavior of the AlertDialog` ... no words.

Comment: AlertDialog is very useful, not rude, Below comments are really rude, here

Answer (score 2):

> android.app.AlertDialog require API level 21 so used android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: Thank you so much... :) It worked.. Can you plz guide how to increase reputations in stack overflow..?

Comment: But answering the questions requires at least 20 reputation how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Set custom layout for `AlertDialog` as:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_message, null);
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setView(dialogView)
                    ....
```

Problem is occurring because there are two version of [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28int%29) method available in [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) :

**First**  [setView (View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28int%29) method is available from *API LEVEL 1* which takes a View object as parameter.

**Second** [setView (int layoutResId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28int%29) method is available from *API LEVEL 21* which takes a layout id  as parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much... :) It worked.. Can you plz guide how to increase reputations in stack overflow..?